# Client error response [url] https://api.mailgun.net/v2/sandboxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org/messages.mime [status code] 400 [reason phrase] BAD REQUEST

Tags: laravel-4, mailgun, laravel-4.2

Client error response [url] https://api.mailgun.net/v2/sandboxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org/messages.mime [status code] 400 [reason phrase] BAD REQUEST

I'm using Laravel 4.2 and guzzlehttp 4.
Sometime mail sending, sometime occurs this error.

Have any solution ?

Comment: Check my answer and accept if it is useful.

Answer (score 3):

Add your domain and secret under `/config/services.php` and try again.
Or you can use `bogardo/mailgun` package to send mail using `mailgun` in `laravel`.

Comment: I'm using sandbox cred. Mail only goes to my mailgun's registered mail id.